# How to restart a Nativescript application even if user closes the app?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

Users might close my application by swiping them from recent apps because they are used to that. In those cases, users don't get notifications about important events and they are complaining about this. How can I restart a force-closed app so that it will continue to receive FCM messages?

Answer (score 1):

FCM messages are supposed to be received in background. A notification should be shown in the device's tray even if you application is not running / suspended.

Comment: If application is on background or suspended by the system, it continues to receive messages. But I am talking about "force-closed" apps, the ones you close by swiping from recent apps. In that case, app is totally killed and doesn't receive fcm messages until you open it again.

Comment: The FCM messages will be received even if the application is not started at all (or "force-closed") - you just need to follow the Firebase plugin instruction to register the messaging service and Android will handle the rest - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md

Comment: I found out that you continue to get notification messages even if app is force-closed but you don't get data messages in that case. Also some android devices stop your app receive data messages even if app is running in background but they are not too common.

Comment: You do get data message also. You have to make sure your FCM doesn't contain the notification, then your data will come through just fine.